# error: incomplete type ... used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

I would like to know why this code does not compile, giving the error: incomplete type  std::tuple_size < aveure > used in nested name specifier

I would expect to have a runtime error in case functions did not match to types but not even to be able to compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>

struct aveure{
    int que;
};

template<typename T>
void prova(T valor){
    int s;
    if (typeid( valor ) == typeid( aveure )) // Even having if (true) 
                                             // would cause the same error
        s=valor.que;
    else
        s = std::tuple_size< T >::value; // ERROR !!! Even when T is a 
                                         //  struct aveure, not a tuple
    std::cout << s;
}

int main() {
    aveure qui;
    qui.que=2;
    prova<aveure>(qui);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this error can be solved splitting the functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>

struct aveure{
    int que;
};

template< typename T >
int len(T val){

    return( std::tuple_size< T >::value );
}

template<>
int len(aveure quan){
    return quan.que;
}


template<typename T>
void prova(T valor){
    int s = len(valor);

    std::cout << s<<std::endl;
    }

int main() {
    aveure qui;
    qui.que=2;
    prova<aveure>(qui);                             // returns 2
    auto first = std::make_tuple (10,'a',"hola");
    prova<decltype(first)>(first);                  // returns 3

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any better solution to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write static code checks like that. With C++, every line in a function must be compilable. In a template function, every line must be valid for every type that it's called with. Thus:

```
template <typename T>
void prova(T valor){
    int s;
    if (typeid( valor ) == typeid( aveure ))
        s = valor.que; // valid ONLY for aveure
    else
        s = std::tuple_size< T >::value; // valid ONLY for std::tuple
    std::cout << s;
}
```

As a result, this function has no hope of compiling. What you can do instead is just provide overloads for `prova` for the two different cases:

```
void prova(aveure valor) {
    std::cout << valor.que;
}

template <typename... Args>
void prova(std::tuple<Args...> ) {
    std::cout << sizeof...(Args);
}
```

Or you can use what is called [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). Your if statement has to be restructed in a way that the compiler will only ever compile one or the other branch and only for valid types. This is what your logic directly translates to:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, aveure>::value // T is an aveure
>::type
prova(T valor) {
    std::cout << valor.que;
```

}

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<T, aveure>::value // else { ... }
>::type
prova(T valor) {
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>::value;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Barry. Very useful. I have found two good articles to complement your point about SFINAE: [link](http://oopscenities.net/2012/04/30/c-sfinae/) and [link](https://debugfailure.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/understanding-sfinae/). I will keep with my proposed solution anyway because SFINAE is not needed when discriminating plain types rather than properties of these types (e. g. iterativity, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, the type is not completely specified. You would have to do something like:

```
std::tuple<decltype(valor)> mytuple;
...
s = std::tuple_size<decltype(mytuple)>::value;
```

The main problem though is:
    s=valor.que;
Every typename T passed to prova(T) must support T::que. 
You can't get aroud this with if-else.

I suppose that since you know the exact type of T at this point, you can get away with a cast:

s=((aveure *) &valor)->que;

But this is not recommended.

Finally you could add a cast operator to aveure and not bother with dereferencing:
    struct aveure{
        int que;
        operator int() {return que;}
    };

```
...

if (typeid( valor ).name() == typeid( aveure ).name())
    s=valor; // no need for s=valor.que
```